# Managing Ground Return for High Surge Currents in LED Capacitor Discharge Circuit

Tags: current, pcb-design, ground, grounding, surge-protection

[image]I have a use-case in which I require four bulk capacitors (470uF) charged to 6.4V. Each separate bulk capacitor will be used to provide the necessary energy to pulse a string of three LEDs at 5μs pulse durations (four strings of three LEDs in total). The peak current for each LED is expected to be 6.4A, leading to a worst-case scenario of 19.2A per string and a total combined current of 76.8A when all strings are flashed simultaneously.

My system is designed such that the battery's maximum output to the system load will not exceed 4A, thanks to current limiting at the battery's positive terminal. However, due to the capacitors being slowly charged and then rapidly discharged, the surge current in the ground return path is significantly higher than what the battery typically outputs.

My primary concern revolves around the ground return path for this surge current. Specifically, I'm wondering if a battery's negative terminal can typically handle such high surge currents without issue. If not, are there alternative strategies or solutions for grounding this amount of current?

I apologize if this is a dumb question. I am still new to circuit design.

The following are the specifications of my specific Li-Ion battery:
Nominal Voltage: 7.2 V
Typical Capacity: 3350 mAh
Over Current Protection Range: 7.1 A - 8.7 A
Max. Discharging Current: 1.5 C
(LI NCR18650-BF 2s1p)

Comment: The surge current ground return will go to the capacitors

Comment: If the battery positive has limited current, why would battery negative have much larger current? That would break the laws of physics. So it does not make sense. Please draw a diagram.

Comment: @Justme While the total energy transferred to and from the battery remains the same over time, the instantaneous current rates are significantly different. Whereas battery positive will experience a limited 4A constant over time, battery negative will experience an instantaneous 76.8A. Does this instantaneous current into battery negative not matter so long as it is equal to the combined current outputted by the battery over time in order to charge the capacitors?

Comment: @NickRand Current does not work like that. At every moment and instant, current entering and exiting battery must be equal. So either the peak is 4A for both terminals or 76.8A for both terminals. Please draw a diagram.

Comment: @Justme Thank you for your replies, I have added the schematic diagram for a single of my LED strings to the post.

Comment: The pulse will not go into the battery. All the energy contributed by the battery has already been put into the capacitor; there is nothing that will "shove" current into the battery.

Comment: @RoyC Thank you for your reply. So, the positive side of the capacitor, the LEDs, and the negative side of the capacitor would form its own loop, thus completing the circuit?

Comment: @vir I believe I understand now. Thank you all for your patience with me, I now realize that my question didn't really make sense in the first place.

Comment: You don’t want to use a battery surge protection for charging the cap. You can use an inductor, resistor, linear limitter or switched limitter as a cap charger.

Comment: As others say, the battery is not included in the capacitor's discharge path.  As Tim note - the battery is loaded by the discharge but the capacitor discharge current does not flow in the battery. || For interest, what is the application?,|| presumably that a LiFePO4 battery given the voltage, and IR LEDs ? [[edited]]

Comment: @MichalPodmanický Understood. As of now, I have a current-limiting IC at the output of my battery (7.2V nominal), which then outputs into a buck converter (6.4V), which then charges my capacitor. I believe this should suffice?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Those are indeed IR LEDs. It is a high-speed IR LED strobe/flash system meant for stroboscopic imaging. I plan to take multiple imprinted images of a fast-moving object. The battery's voltage is actually 7.2V nominal, however I used 6.4V in the above diagram to represent a voltage source to avoid confusion as my original post had mentioned 6.4V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Charge is drawn from the capacitor *and* battery, according to their relative impedance.

Since the pulse is short, the capacitor's impedance can be quite low without needing massive values; pay attention to not just the value, but the ESR, as ESR will dominate for most types at these frequencies (~100kHz).  You will probably want to consider aluminum polymer types.

The battery's impedance can be increased by adding a series resistor, an LC filter network, or an active current limiting circuit.  Consider:

[image]

The LED current is carried by C1, and BT1 with ESR indicated (circled), as a current divider between them.

For a battery current limit around 8A and a peak total load of 80A, the impedance divider needs to be 1:10.  If the capacitor is say 20mΩ, the battery needs to be more than 200mΩ at these frequencies.

Offhand, I would guess the battery impedance is lower than this.  But it depends.  It's hard to say, even given a datasheet, as they aren't concerned about time scales this short; in general, batteries do have capacitance (the impedance of the electrodes and electrolyte acting together, apart from the effect of chemical equilibria which is mediated by ionic diffusion in the ms+ time scales), so the impedance at these frequencies may be limited more by cable inductance than internal resistance.

A resistor is a fine way to provide this impedance, when the duty cycle is very low.  It sounds like this might be such an application (strobe light?).  More generally, C1 and the added resistor, can be an extended CLC.. network which filters the current ripple from the left side, away from the battery; the design of this is covered by power supply filtering design guides.

Note that 200mΩ at 100kHz corresponds to 3.2µH, so cable lengths on the order of this (stray inductance goes as length times μ<sub>0</sub>, times a geometry factor typically 0.2-0.5; ballpark 0.5µH/m is a good start), i.e. 6m or so, would be reasonable to provide such impedance.  That's probably unrealistic for a portable device, so the resistor, filter network, or active limiter, is likely preferred here.

80A in 5µs is moderately fast, and you may find it's worth switching (and bypassing, and supplying/filtering, potentially) the LED strings individually, rather than all together.  Consider the stray inductance of the LED-switch-capacitor loop and what dI/dt the switching speed will generate.  You may also need a TVS across the MOSFET (S to D) to clamp flyback voltage at turn-off.